# parameters without type annotation swift

Tags: swift

I have a function that checks the type of arguments it takes in but it seems difficult for me to define a parameter that can work with any type annotation. Here's my been-trying:

```
//bool
var x = 0, y = 3.142, z = "hello"
func checkType(input: /*here's my problem*/) -> String {
    let res = "That is of type \(input.dynamicType)"
    return  res
}
print(checkType(//argument))
//
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You answered yourself

> [...] that can work with **any** type [...]

Here's the code

```
func checkType(input: Any) -> String {
    let res = "That is of type \(input.dynamicType)"
    return  res
}
```

Test

```
checkType("Hello") // "That is of type String"
checkType(true) // "That is of type Bool"
checkType(123) // "That is of type Int"
```

Comment: For some reason someone has downvote this right answer, please next time explain your downvotes..